# html meta viewport tag not working when device language set to chinese

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, meta-tags

I am developing a webapp using angularjs and jquery. The webapp loads perfectly fine when the mobile device language is set to any except Chinese. I debugged a lot and found the issue that the web app is not loading because of the meta view port tag in the index.html. As soon as I remove the meta viewport tag, the web app loads successfully in the mobile when the language is set to Chinese.
navigator.language = `"zh-CN"`
But I cannot remove the meta viewport tag from the index.html , just for the webapp to load when the language is set to Chinese.
May I know the reason why the meta viewport tag is creating this problem when navigator.language is set to Chinese ?
Is there any other alternate solution to make my webapp working with the meta viewport tag ?

Below is the code that I have in `index.html`

```
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=360.1, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
<meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"/>
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"/>
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black"/>
<meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no"/>
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
 <title>Test</title>
```

The above will not work if mobile language is set to zh-CN. But works fine if I remove the viewport tag.

Please help on this. Appreciate all your inputs.

Comment: use this <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> inplace of  <meta charset="utf-8"/>

Comment: else paste your entire <head> in the question,Which browser/device it is not working,test it in all browser,and edit question,because ideally it should work

Comment: ideally it should work, edit you question and paste your  entire <head> in the question,Which browser/device it is not working

Comment: Added the head of the my application...Please see above.. I am testing in chrome browser of Samsung Galaxy S3 and S4

Comment: The issue is seen only when the device language is set to Chinese. I have created a sample app also and can see the issue their as well. The issue is <meta name="viewport" content="width=360.1, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">   , if i remove the width and initial scale..it will work properly... 
The below meta tag works fine 
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no,maximum-scale=1.0"> . .Issue is observed if we add width and initial-scale. I can also share the index.html which anyone can try in your local apache server and reproduce the issue. Please help

Comment: Share,please..cant reproduce at my end

Comment: @ShekharPankaj I am not able to paste the index.html here. Also there is no option to attach it.. Any alternate to share ?

Comment: After again debugging, i found that issue is with "initial-scale" . If initial-scale is set to 1.0 , it doesn't render properly, but if set to 0 , then it loads successfully.. May I know why is this happening ? <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0,maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no/>